# Letter without "from address" and "to address" and no indention for letter text?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I want to write a private letter where I don't need the address fields. The letter should start with "Dear xx". I know it's a stupid question but I want to know if it is easily possible. I have made a lot of definitions in a lco file and want to reuse them without using another template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most basic approach, if you don't want any of the "letter" attributes, is to set the document as-is (not using `\opening`, `\closing`, ...):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\hfill\today

Dear XX

This is a personal letter

Sincerely,

Me
\end{document}
```

Comment: *facepalm* ok, I was definitely thinking to complicated... ;) Thx!

Comment: @user4811: Of course, I've just shown a basic usage. You can add all your fancy-shmancy definitions as needed. For example, you might be interested in using something like `\medskip` between the opening and the start of the letter (and elsewhere).